# Error while consuming asmx web service using https

Tags: .net, web-services, ssl, https, asmx

I have a problem while trying to consume asmx web service from a web application, both the web application and the web service are under https.

I got the error : "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive." after calling the web service.
The web service was working perfectly under http.

Does anyone have any ideas about this issue ??

Comment: N.B: This error occured when i'm using a valid cerificate and when I'm using a self signed certificate generated from IIS it works perfectly.